# Add product to quote, if he has zero stock qty

Tags: magento2, product, stock, qty, add

How i can add product (for example with 10 qty) to quote if this product has 0 stock qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable backorders for this product.
To reach this you should make product qty - 0, click on the `Advanced Inventory`, set `Out-of-Stock Threshold` to your needed qty, and set `Backorders` to `Allow Qty Bellow 0`

In case you place the order with 10 qty of this product, product's Salable Quantity will be -10.

[image]

[image]